# Why we need to use Solo in Development and Kafka in Production in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, ibm-blockchain

Please explain the difference between the Solo and Kafka.
1)Why we need  to use Solo in Development and Kafka in Production on Hyperledger Fabric?
2)Can we use only Kafka for both Development and Production?
3)How the Consensus mechanism exactly work in Hyperledger Fabric, can anyone 
explain with example ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

1. There is no reason you cannot use a Kafka-based orderer in
   development; however if you are developing on a local machine the
   Solo orderer requires much less overhead to get up and running
2. Yes (see answer above)
3. Suggest you read https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/txflow.html first and then ask question in the Hyperledger Rocket Chat

Answer (score 0):

1) One important reason to use Kafka in production is that it will be more fault tolerant than solo. You only have a single orderer with solo and that is a single point of failure.

2) Yes you can

3) See: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/kafka.html